# Why does a python list do this?

Tags: python, list

I wanted to make a copy of a list in python while also removing one element:

```
x = [1,2,3]
a = list(x).remove(2)
```

While `x` was still `[1,2,3]` as expected, `a` was `None` instead of the `[1,3]` that I expected.

I get the expected behavior if I break line 2 into two lines:

```
x = [1,2,3]
a = list(x)
a.remove(2)
```

`a` is now `[1,3]` with x unmodified.

Why is this?

Comment: In general `x = obj.method1().method2()` will call `method1` on `obj` and `method2` on the *return value* of `obj.method1()`. And the return value of `method2` will be what is assigned to the variable `x`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.remove()` method modifies the list itself, it does not return the modified list. For example:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
x.remove(2)
print x
```

result:

```
[1, 3]
```

In general, [most list methods](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) modify the list in-place. There are built-ins for some methods (like `sorted` for `.sort()`) that return the modified list but there are none for `.remove()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you do need to copy your list, there are several options, but I prefer:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = x[:]
x.remove(2)
print x, y
```

this prints:

```
[1, 3] [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Why do you prefer that?

Comment: Here is a link to a question asking how to clone a list.  Of all of the options listed in the top answer, I feel that slicing, y = x[:], is the simplest (though not necessarily intuitive that you would be making a copy).http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python